# Strange behaviour of UIScrollView in XCODE 8 without autolayout

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, xcode8

I just update my xcode from 7.3 to 8 and facing some strange behaviour for all UISrollviews. While testing in device  subview inside the scrollview is aligned to the center of the screen but in storyboard it is arranged very well.I am not getting any clue for this unexpected behaviour. Please help ..

Comment: Please provide more information about you've already done so far : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use Autolayout then it will work properly

Comment: I face the same issue in xcode8 for Scrollview without autolayout

Comment: Did I need to make entire storyboard autolayout? or particular scrollview only?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add one more Child View with in scroll view with named (scrollContainerVw) and set following pins :
[image]
[image]
for both scroll view and child view.

If you want to support multiple screen Please add following code in view did load :

```
    self.scrollVw.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width
    self.scrollVw.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height
    self.scrollContainerVw.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width
    self.scrollContainerVw.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height
```